# Не могу понять, где допустил ошибку в коде

Tags: pascal

[image: Это тип программа на листке]

```
program z51;
var 
  n,m,p,k:integer;
begin
  n := 35;
  m := 15;
  p := 4;
  k := 0;

  if (n <= 35) or (p < 3) then
  begin
    k := m div(p-2);
    if (m div(p-2) <> 0) then
    begin
      k := (m + n) div p + k;
      k := k + 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      k := (n-m)mod(p-1)+k;
      k := k - 1;
    end
    else
      if ((m + n) div (p + 3) > 2) then
        k := k + 1;
  end
  Writeln(k);
end.
```

Помогите плиз. Это Pascal

Answer (score 4):

Вы написали `div` там, где в блок-схеме стоит `mod`. У Вас неправильно расставлены `begin`-ы и `end`-ы. Поставьте предпоследний `end` перед последним `else`. И точку с запятой после одного из `end`-ов.

Comment: хммм, все равно ругается, перед последним else ждет какой то оператор. div поменял на mod, и точку с запятой поставил.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не пренебрегайте форматированием кода, это наглядно помогает искать такие ошибки.
2. Комментарии тоже бывают полезны.

```
program z51;
var 
  n,m,p,k:integer;
begin
  n := 35;
  m := 15;
  p := 4;
  k := 0;

  if (n <= 35) or (p < 3) then     
  begin // обрабатываем левую половину
    k := m div (p-2);
    if (m mod (p-2) <> 0) then
    begin
      k := (m + n) div p + k;
      k := k + 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      k := (n-m)mod(p-1)+k;
      k := k - 1;
    end;
  end // закончили обрабатывать левую половину     
  else
  begin // обрабатываем правую половину
    if ((m + n) div (p + 3) > 2) then
      k := k + 1;
  end // закончили обрабатывать правую половину
  Writeln(k);
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
program z51;
Var 
   n,m,p,k:integer;
Begin
  n := 35;
  m := 15;
  p := 4;
  k := 0;
if (n <= 35) or (p < 3) then
  begin
    k := m div(p-2);
      if (m div(p-2) <> 0) then
        begin
          k := (m + n) div p + k;
          k := k + 1;
        end
      else
        begin
           k := (n-m)mod(p-1)+k;
           k := k - 1;
        end;

      if ((m + n) div (p + 3) > 2) then
         k := k + 1;
  end;
  Writeln(k); // 21
end.
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы разбавьте код и ответ словами - что было неправильно, что изменилось и т.п.